Sharing packages between different Python versions
I am using KDE Neon jammy 22.04 (Ubuntu based). It cames with Python3.10 installed. I also installed Python3.11 with sudo apt install python3.11. I wrote a program using PyQt5. It works with Python3.10, but not Python3.11. My error is ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.sip'.
PyQt5 is in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/.  It is present neither in /usr/lib/python3.10 nor /usr/lib/python3.11. /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ and /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/ are empty. When I do :
$ python3.11 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"

I can see
['', '/usr/lib/python311.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.11', '/usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/home/richard/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

So apparently my Python3.11 go in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages where PyQt5 is... the folder with PyQt5 is present.
Why my PyQt5 program doesn't work with my Python3.11 ? Why it says No module named 'PyQt5.sip' ? There is no difference between my package in python3.10 and python3.11.

If the package is truly the same across python versions, you could probably resolve this with a symlink. But in general packages are stored solely within the specific python distribution that they were installed for. You could also simply install pyqt5 for Python3.11.

I'm not familiar with the convention and behavior of dist-packages, but, in any case, most modules need to be rebuilt for each specific python version (and they can possibly be incompatible with it).

The dist-packages directory is meant only for packages installed by apt, and will contain *.so files which are specific to the version of Python they were compiled for. This is in contrast to pip-installed packages, which go in a version-specific site-packages directory. It rarely makes any sense to share packages between Python installations, since a package (or any one of its dependencies) could use syntax and/or features that are only provided by a specific version of Python. (To exaggerate the point: imagine you have both Python-2.7 and Python-3.10 installed).

I agree with you ekhumoro. But why when I install Python3.11 (sudo apt install Python3.11), it doesn't install all the packages ? PyQt5 is part of packages installed with Python, right ? It should be available. I have another laptop (Manjaro Linux) with only Pyton3.11, and when I check /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/, I have all the packages included PyQt5. However, on my KDE Neon, packages are included in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/. The site-packages folder doesn't exist for both python3.10 et python3.11. However, Python3.10 can import PyQt5, Python3.11 can't...

PyQt5 certainly isn't part of Python: it must always be installed separately. The PyQt packages provided by your Linux distro were compiled for Python-3.10; they shouldn't be used with any other version of Python. The dist-packages system is specific to Debian/Ubuntu. Manjaro is based on Arch-linux, so it's not relevant. If you want PyQt5 for Python-3.11, you must either compile and install it yourself, find some pre-compiled packages, or use pip to install a local copy (e.g. pip3.11 install --user PyQt5). Warning: do not ever use sudo pip as you could easily break your system.

PS: I would strongly advise you to educate yourself regarding the way Python packages are handled on Debian/Ubuntu systems. It's very easy to trash the parts of your system that depend on Python if you don't know what you're doing. See e.g. Ubuntu: What is the best way to install Python packages? and Python, Debian, and the install locations.
